# Pass by Reference from C#, Through C.L.I. to Unmanaged C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll, static-libraries, command-line-interface

I've seen a number of articles on this subject but none have helped me solve my issue. In essence, I want to be able to pass a variable by reference from C#, through a C.L.I. wrapper to a C++ library, modify the variable, and have it passed back up through the functions without using the return value.

The code I currently have is as follows:

In C#:

```
[DllImport("UtilitiesWrapper.dll", EntryPoint = "Increment", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void _Increment(int number);

int value;
_Increment( value);
```

In the C.L.I. wrapper:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec( dllexport) void __cdecl Increment( int& number);
};

void __cdecl Increment( int& number) {
    NS_UtilitiesLib::Increment( number);
}
```

In C++:

```
namespace NS_UtilitiesLib {
    static void Increment( int& number) {
        ++number;
    }
}
```

It keeps giving me an error about memory being corrupt at the end of the C.L.I. function which I presume is because it can't understand how to put the C# variable into the parameter (as when I step through the C.L.I. it never picks up the original value). I have tried using [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] when declaring the function in C# with DllImport but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Why is a return value unacceptable?

Comment: Because later in the project I may want multiple values returned from a function, or use the return value to indicate success or failue.

Comment: `ref` http://joshhendo.com/2011/02/pass-by-reference-from-c-to-c/

Comment: have you tried trying public static extern void _Increment(ref int number)?  Not sure if that would even be allowed, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=c%23+pass+reference+c%2B%2B) to find [this](http://joshhendo.com/2011/02/pass-by-reference-from-c-to-c/):

```
[DllImport("ImportDLL.dll")]
public static extern void MyFunction(ref myInteger);
```

Presumably the author intended `ref int myInteger` but the point stands: use the `ref` keyword.

Comment: The link is broken. So on managed side use `ref int`. And on unmanaged side merely use `int&`? Isn't pinning necessary?

Comment: Depends. If you wait synchronously for the call to external function to finish without leaving the stack where variable  was declared then no. Or if variable is a class field and instance of that class will live long enough for external function to finish then also no. Otherwise. if you cant ensure either then pass by value.